# mipsel-linux-gcc is throwing 'undefined reference to 'timer_create'' linking error even though -lrt is mentioned

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, mips32

I am using 'timer_create', 'timer_settime' apis in my program. My PC environment is Ubuntu and i am building application for my smart device whose architecture is MIPS 32 bit.

Following is the linking error i am facing while build my program:

> '**MyProgram.c:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `timer_create'
>    MyProgram.c:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to`timer_settime'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**'.

This is the command i used to build my program:

```
mipsel-linux-gcc MyProgram.c -L/home/buildroot-gcc342/lib -lrt -o MyProgram.o
```

'mipsel-linux-gcc' is the compiler for MIPS 32 platform.

Comment: Your error message refers to MyProgram.c but you only compile TimerHandlerPrg.c. Please post real messages and real commands.

Comment: Typo Error. Corrected

Comment: Presumably, your librt.so is in /home/buildroot-gcc342/lib?. Can you show us the output of "file librt.so"? Also show the output of "objdump -T librt.so | grep timer_create"

Comment: when i run the command 'file librt.so' following is the output:

librt-0.9.28.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

librt.so is the symbolic link of 'librt-0.9.28.so'.

And when i run this command: objdump -T librt.so | grep timer_create. There is no output. It means it doesnt have defination of 'timer_create' api?

Comment: And to add one more point: i am using static library librt.a in my make file. Is there any command to check whether librt.a has defination of 'timer_create'?